# Identify updated rows in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with lot of columns one of them is date_incoming_goods and another one is last_update, The issue is , there is no surrogate key in the table and I cannot change it.

So the table looks like this, for simplicity I will ignore lot of columns.

```
supplier  item     turnover   date_incoming_goods  last_update
supp1     glasses  100        15.1.2022              15.1.2022
supp2     chairs   200        15.1.2022              15.1.2022
```

Each day the table gets updated. Either new rows will come or there is a change in the first 3 columns. So I can see when the table got updated last time and that's all. I would like to save the history because row data can be updated and I need to know how it looked like in the previous day or month etc.

let say there was an update on 16.1.2022

```
    supplier  item     turnover   date_incoming_goods  last_update
    supp1     glasses  150        15.1.2022              16.1.2022
    supp2     chairs   200        15.1.2022              16.1.2022
    supp3     tables   500        16.1.2022              16.1.2022
```

I save the base table in another table and then I try to compare but this is not possible because I know which row is a new one because on 15.1.2022 update there were just 2 rows but I don't have any surrogate key in the base table how can I find out that the first row has an update in the column TURNOVER from 100 to 150 ?

Comment: create a trigger on the table and write old/new values to a history table?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of options you could consider

1. Flashback data archive

This will create a internal mechanism which will capture all changes, and then you would use the VERSIONS BETWEEN syntax to generate an audit history of the row changes from a nominated point in time.

A full tutorial/demo on that here

https://youtu.be/qIs2UPIodQg

2. Audit triggers

You can create row level triggers to capture before/after images of the data and log that to a secondary table. If that all seems a lot of work, I've a utility which will automate that so that all you need is an API call to generate the triggers etc.

https://github.com/connormcd/audit_utility/tree/master/v2

Comment: I would do that of course but there is one issue. The base table resides in a schema where I have just SELECT permission. So Idon't have a possibility to create any trigger erc. otherwise admin could create something like scd2 with open and close date to see which row is actual and which one could be use if we query past days or months.  Therefore my i te tio. was to copy everything first in another scheme with all permissions and create scd2 mechanism. but I need to compare with the base table which rows got updated but how if there is no surrogate key.